# Unable to run flutter mobile app due to null checker issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, null-safety

I'm trying to connect firebase to my flutter app. All the features are working fine, when running as a web app. But when I'm trying to run the mobile app, the app isn't running and showing an error message as below in the terminal.

```
E/flutter ( 4635): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 4635): #0      MethodChannel.binaryMessenger
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:142
E/flutter ( 4635): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:148
E/flutter ( 4635): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:331
E/flutter ( 4635): #3      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:344
```

Below are the dependencies, I'm using:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "0.5.1"
  firebase_auth: "0.18.2"
  cloud_firestore: "0.14.2"
```

Below is my main.dart file

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: Login(),
  ));
}
```

While running Flutter channel:

```
PS C:\Users\hp\Documents\firebase\blog_app> flutter channel
Flutter channels:
  master
  dev
  beta
* stable
```

Comment: Please post screenshot after running "flutter channel" command. Want to see if you are on a stable channel or any other

Comment: Also check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712031/flutter-2-0-2-null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value

Comment: @TahaAsif added it

Comment: Show the code where error occurs.

Comment: @ProblematicDude there isn't any errors in the code I have written. It shows errors in the firebase.dart files - inbuilt fires of the firebase library

Comment: It's not your fault, actually. One of your package is messing things up.

Comment: "Null check operator used on a null value" error also occurs when you are sending the wrong fields to firebase. For instance, one of the docs from firebase could be missing a field and that caused the null check operator to show itself. Therefore, double check if you are sending right fields.

Comment: @TahaAsif it's working fine for web

Answer (score 0):

change your pubspec.yaml as follows.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
```

and run `flutter put get` in terminal

Then run `flutter channel stable`, `flutter upgrade` and `flutter clean` in terminal